# If statement for React Routing from query

Tags: reactjs, routes, rendering

I have the following question regarding React and react routing.
I'm trying to do the routing based on what countries and projects that get returned from my query. Basically, I believe I need an if statement to see if the _id of each title is project or country so that the correct corresponding component gets returned (either RenderCountry or RenderProject).

```
     componentDidMount() {
    client

      .fetch('*[_type == "land" || _type =="project"] {title, slug, _type }')
      .then(country => this.setState({ country }));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {this.state.country.map(post => (
          <Route
            path={`/${post.slug.current}`}
            exact
            component={RenderCountry}
          />
        ))}
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/countries" exact component={Countries} />
        <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
        <Route component={FouroFour} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

Looking forward to your reply!
This is the results from the query:

```
    {
  _type: "land",
  slug: {
    _type: "slug",
    current: "namibia"
  },
  title: "Namibia"
}
{
  _type: "land",
  slug: {
    _type: "slug",
    current: "niger"
  },
  title: "Niger"
}
{
  _type: "project",
  slug: {
    _type: "slug",
    current: "self-help-or-social-transformation"
  },
  title: "Self help or social transformation"
}
{
  _type: "project",
  slug: {
    _type: "slug",
    current: "mozambique-norway-accessibility-partnership"
  },
  title: "Mozambique/Norway Accessibility Partnership"
}
{
  _type: "project",
  slug: {
    _type: "slug",
    current: "matching-education-skills-and-work"
  },
  title: "Matching education, skills and work"
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Is there something not working as expected in the code example you posted?

Comment: Im sorry that i have not explained it well enough. i will update the post with furter explenation. 
But for now: In the .map, i need the component to render either Render country or RenderProject based on what the _id of the current element in the .map is.

Comment: none of your code has `_id`. do you mean `_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're almost there with the example code you posted. You're already mapping over all the data to create new `<Route />` components. During this mapping you have access to the `_type`, so you can determine which `component` prop to pass to the route based on that.

Something like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {this.state.country.map(post => (
          <Route
            path={`/${post.slug.current}`}
            exact
            component={post._type === 'country' ? RenderCountry : RenderProject}
          />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    );
  }
```

If you have different type of components to render for each `post._type`, it might be better to create a mapping, so you will have something like:

```
const routeComponentMap = {
  land: RenderCountry,
  project: RenderProject
};

export class RenderRoute extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      country: [],
      project: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    client
      .fetch('*[_type == "land" || _type =="project"] {title, slug, _type }')
      .then(country => this.setState({ country }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {this.state.country.map(post => (
          <Route
            path={`/${post.slug.current}`}
            exact
            component={routeComponentMap[post._type]}
          />
        ))}
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/countries" exact component={Countries} />
        <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
        <Route component={FouroFour} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Niekert! this looks like the correct solution, but I am having some trouble implementing it, this is my try
https://dpaste.de/6eHb#L16 

The website shows the error 
` TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined" `, this is for line 38 where const routes is defined

Comment: Make sure you run put `const routes = ...` inside the `render` function! Sorry, I omitted some of the surrounding code to make my answer a bit shorter.

Comment: That fixed country! (we have called it "land"), but for some weird reason it only works for country and still not for project
https://dpaste.de/MDye <- code as is 

it may help to see the json too, but we have no problem calling "project" in code 
https://dpaste.de/YfXv <- the json output we work with

Also you have been a tremendous help so far Niekert, thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm judging from the code examples I would say maybe you mean it **does not** work for country, but does for project? 

I think this is happening because in the `routeComponentMap` it's `country: RenderCountry`, but instead it should be `land: RenderCountry` (because the `_type` will be `land` instead of `country`, which it now tries to look for. Updated my example as well. No problem!

Comment: no it works fine for country, but not for project. It's very weird. we saw the country/land problem ourselves :) . thank you for the updated example!

Comment: It seems the error was elsewhere in my project, thank you Niekert, you sollution was correct.